# Change text in a div if another div has a specific attribute

Tags: javascript

I would like to change a text in a div if another div has a specific attribute, in my case `data-value`.

In the specific if a div has an attribute `data-value="cars"` another div should have the text "Buy".

In the specific if `data-value="cars"` I would like to change the text "1" into "Buy"

`<div class="one">1</div>`

Here the sample code

```
<div class="dynamic">
  <div class="content">
   <div data-value="cars">
   Cars
   </div>
   <div data-value="truck">
   Truck
   </div>
   <div data-value="moto">
   Moto
   </div>
 </div>
</div>



<div class="change">
 <div>
 1
 </div>
 <div>
 2
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that in JS?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to understand or reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question, and not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: Yeah you can make your code run directly in StackOverflow with the `<>` button 

Comment: What have you tried, where exactly did you run into problems?

Answer (score 0):

you need to first perform a query on the existence of any element within the `content` having the `data-value` attribute of `"cars"`

use the `document.querySelector()` function

```
  if (document.querySelector('.dynamic .content [data-value="cars"]')) ...
```

then you need to set the text content of all the div elements within the `change` that have the value `1`, using the `.textContent` attribute

```
document.querySelectorAll('.change div')
  .forEach(div => if( div.textContent=="1") div.textContent="Buy");
```

putting all pieces together

```
  if (document.querySelector('.dynamic .content [data-value="cars"]')) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.change div')
    .forEach(div => if(div.textContent=="1") div.textContent="Buy" );
  }
```

Comment: Hi PA. Does this also work if I don't have the class .one?

In my case not always that div have a class.

Comment: so update your question to state exactly what is the way to identify the target element for the text update.

Comment: @PH, just updated my question.